# Calculate the multiplication of two columns in a KPI

Tags: sql, dax, ssas, tabular

I have the following KPI in SQL :

```
SELECT SUM(AmountByDay * WorkedDays) FROM Employee
```

I tried to translate it to DAX :

```
KPISalary := SUM(AmountByDay * WorkedDays)
```

But it's getting me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try SUMX() :

```
KPISalary := SUMX(
Employee,

'Employee'[AmountByDay] * 'Employee'[WorkedDays]
)
```